# How to ADD NEW STRING VALUE in android studio?

Tags: android

I'm having trouble adding new string value to the buttons. I need to follow these instructions:

> To change the text attribute of Button 0, click the ellipsis to the
>   right of the attribute in the attribute window and click Add new
>   resources in the upper right corner of the window and then add a New
>   string Value. Enter s0 as the Resource name and ZERO as its value.
>   Click ok and note that the text attribute of this button has become:
>   @string/s0.

But I'm unable to figure out what ellipsis is.
[image]

Comment: It will be showing as @string/s0 in studio but the apk will have ZERO in the button

Comment: Where u found the word "ellipsis"?

Comment: Oh got it!, Thanks @SayokMajumder , i created a new string value, and then assigned the constraint!